# Perl libxml findvalue fails when root tag contains attributes

Tags: perl, libxml2

I am trying to filter records in a given XML file matching the contract ids contained in a CSV file.

The xml file looks like this:

```
<ROOTS02 xmlns="http://www.fja.com/RAN/RANTS02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fja.com/RAN/RANTS02 RANTS02.xsd">
<Record>
<Date>27.02.2023</Date>
<Year>2022</Year>
<ContractID>115000520</ContractID>
<Data>
... some more fields ...
</Data>
</Record>
<Record>
</Record>
....
</ROOTS02>
```

My perl code look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;
my $xml_parser = XML::LibXML->new();

my $xml_file="data0.xml";
my $vidfile="contractids.txt";
my $output="out0.xml";
my $roottag='ROOTS02';
my $rectag='Record';
my $filtertag='ContractID';
my $element;
my %vidtable;



readcontractids($vidfile);

print "Parsing input file $xml_file....";
my $xml_doc = $xml_parser->parse_file($xml_file);
#parsefile($input);
my $root = $xml_doc->documentElement();
my @records = $root->getElementsByTagName($rectag);
open(OUT, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $output);
foreach my $record (@records) {
    my $contract_id = $record->findvalue($filtertag);
    if ( exists $vidtable{$contract_id} ) {
        $record->unbindNode();
        print OUT $record->toString();
    }
}
close OUT;
print "Done!\n";
print "Output written to $output\n";

###########################################
sub readvertragids {
   my $file=shift;
   my $pidold;
   my $pidnew;
   open(FH, '<', $file) or die "Error: $file can't be read :$!";
   while (<FH>) {
      chomp $_;
      if ( ! exists $vidtable{$_} ) {
         $vidtable{$_}=$_;
      }
   }
   close(FH);
}
```

It all works fine if remove the attributes from the ROOTS02 tag in the first line fo the XML file:

With the original first line of the XML file containing the attributes there's no result from the findvalue call for tag 'ContarctID':

```
perl -d ./t5.pl 

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.37
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(./t5.pl:4):      my $xml_parser = XML::LibXML->new();
  DB<1> b 56
  DB<2> r
main::(./t5.pl:56):         if ( exists $vidtable{$contract_id} ) {
  DB<2> Parsing input file rant0.xml....l 50-60
50      #parsefile($input);
51:     my $root = $xml_doc->documentElement();
52:     my @records = $root->getElementsByTagName($rectag);
53:     open(OUT, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $output);
54:     foreach my $record (@records) {
55:         my $contract_id = $record->findvalue($filtertag);
56==>b      if ( exists $vidtable{$contract_id} ) {
57:             $record->unbindNode();
58:             print OUT $record->toString();
59          }
60      }
  DB<3> p $rectag
Record
  DB<4> p $filtertag
ContractID
  DB<5> p $contract_id

  DB<6> p $record
<Record>
<Date>27.02.2023</Date>
<Year>2022</Year>
<ContractID>115000520</ContractID>
...
```

What can I do to make it work even with the attributes in the root tag?
How do the attributes have an influence on the functionality of the libxml functions?

Comment: I don't expect this will be a solution, but I don't find documentation for an instance method of `parse_file`. I use `my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $filename );`.

Comment: @UncleCarl, The XML::LibXML class is documented in [XML::LibXML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/view/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod). This is where you'll find the documentation for the class methods `new` and `load_xml`, and for the instance method `parse_file`.

Comment: @ikegami Yep. I figured I'd need to swim down further into the XML documentation soup.  I guess the class method works better for me, at least when only working on a single file.

Comment: @UncleCarl: `parse_file` comes from `File::Slurp` I guess.

Comment: @Gilles Quénot, No. No relation to File::Slurp. It's a XML::LibXML method as mentioned above. `->new->parse_file` predates `->load_xml`, in fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*I shall use the `{namespace}name` notation.*]

You are looking for a `{}ContractID` node.

But the node in the document is a `{http://www.fja.com/RAN/RANTS02}ContractID` node.

That's because `xmlns=""` sets the default namespace of the associated element, and all descendant elements.

```perl
use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs( r => "http://www.fja.com/RAN/RANTS02" );

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file( "data0.xml" );

for my $rec_node ( $xpc->findnodes( "/r:ROOTS02/r:Record", $doc ) ) {
   my $contract_id = $xpc->findvalue( "r:ContractID", $rec_node );
   ...
}
```

Comment: it works! Thx a lot!

However, an aditional question: 

Is there a more generic way to specify the tag or path in the findvalue call?

I have the problem with a similar xml file containing an aditional level in the records:
'''
<ROOTS02 xmlns="http://www.fja.com/RAN/RANTS02" ....">
<Record>
<Header>
<Date>27.02.2023</Date>
<Year>2022</Year>
<ContractID>115000520</ContractID>
</Header>
<Data>
... some more fields ...
</Data>
</Record>
<Record>
</Record>
....
</ROOTS02>
'''

Comment: `.//r:Record` aka `descendant::r:Record`